# SPSS create variable function in R

Tags: r, function, spss

I am trying to switch from SPSS to R, but I'm still stuck on some aspects of the R logic at the moment. Right now, I am trying to rebuild something like the "create new variable" function from SPSS - exactly the follwing SPSS syntax:

```
COMPUTE ABC_WC  =   1-  ((ABS   (   WC_B    -   WC_A    ))  / ( WC_B +  WC_A + 0.0001))
```

In R, my data frame contains all of the defined variables (`WC_A`  and `WC_B`) as columns with X observations in the line. I need to repeat these analyses for a fixed, repeating number of variables every time I do my analyses - so a more or less automated version of this calculation across all 80 variables would be great.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a data frame called `df` then the following should do the job in R:

```
df$ABC_WC <- 1 - ((abs(df$WC_B - df$WC_A)) / (df$WC_B + df$WC_A + 0.0001))
```

To write a function, try substituting the columns and a data frame by variables. Then write a `for` loop or use `apply`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - if I do this, I get the follwing warning message: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ABC_pronoun", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 188

Comment: it looks like your variables have different names: https://www.r-bloggers.com/translating-weird-r-errors/. for reproducibility, you can post your data frame on SO (by extracting it using `dput(df)`)

Comment: Note SPSS is not case sensitive for variables, but R is.